# ASP.NET MVC Google oauth authorization error. 'Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

When I try to add Google login in my ASP.NET MVC app, follow this resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

I get an error:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy. \n\nIf you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
>
> Learn more
> Request Details
>
> The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google.
> If you're the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.
> redirect_uri=https://localhost:7082/

How should I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the second line of the error message you posted, it tells you what to do.

Comment: seems right but i dont know how it doesnt comply, i follow the guide step by step

Comment: Did you do this "register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console." for this redirect_uri=https://localhost:7082/?  Sorry I can't help more on how to do it as I haven't used Google Cloud only Azure.

Comment: do you mean this section in credentials at Google Cloud Platform? 
"Authorized redirect URLs: 
"

Comment: that sounds like it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Google OAuth for my website. Same error here, It returns an error even though I correctly input my URI to google URI to my [Project](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
I input `http://localhost/glogin/app/welcome.php` and still not working but I just solved it when I added a second URI `http://localhost/glogin/app/example.php` I don't know what's the problem but it just solved my error and fixed it.